# How to do clustering with sklearn having classes in my data set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataset (example):

```
id   f1   f2    f3
a1   4    8      9
a2   9    0      0
a3   4    11     7
a4   3    3      0
a5   1    8      1
```

I can use f1, f2 and f3 to do K-means clustering and get some clusters. But, I want to be able to know which id went to which clusters (for example a1, a3, a4 are in the same cluster, a2 and a5 in other cluster). How to do that? Can I do that with sklearn?

Answer (score 0):

From [description](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) of sklern KMeans class: there is an attribute `labels_` which return cluster numbers for all points in training dataset and for test data there is a method `predict`, which also returns cluster numbers for points in order they were provided. btw  on page with description you can also find *Examples* section where these 2 cases are considered.